# PIC Prgramming - The basic flow of things

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

Can someone please explain to me the basic flow of how this is done.

So currently I a USB pic programmer and also a multi pic adapter. I understand that I can use this to write my program to the PIC. But Im not sure what happens before that, like how do I actually test it with LED or some input sensor etc that gives out analog data?

This is what I have now: http://www.piccircuit.com/shop/pic-programmer/26-ica01-usb-pic-programmer-set.html

So I need to connect this to to a breadboard? And if so how? Im completely lost!! This is the first time that I attempt to do this. What I have done is use my Synapse RF Engine EK2100 to build what I want.

Now what...?

Comment: Just insert a microcontroller in a programmer slot, see instruction to find first pin on both programmer and micrMCU, then follow programmer instruction about how to upload compiled HEX firmware to a MCU

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish but what you purchased is a programmer for PIC microcontrollers.  After you have written some code whether in assembly or C and compiled it to a hex file, this device will put that code onto a PIC microcontroller that you buy separately.  Have you purchased a PIC device to program or do you just have the programmer and the EK2100 kit?  If you provide some more detail we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I just have that programmer the PICCIRCUIT.COM one. Is that just used to actually program the PIC? Do I also need something to "debug" ?

Comment: @Harry yes the easiset thing is to buy a development board with the peripherals that you want to use. piccircuit.com has some of the boards as I remember. Later on, you'll likely want to build your own boards, starting a a breadboard perhaps and the doing a schematic and finally a board layout.

Comment: @Harry Did you get all of the information you were looking for?  If you still have questions feel free to post them here or you are welcome to email me.  My email is on my profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Write a basic 'flash LED' program and then wire-up the PIC to see if it works.

Hot tip - use the internal oscillator to minimise the external component count (makes things simpler). Browse around a PIC savvy site like http://digital-diy.com/ to get lots of interesting ideas and code samples.

The community there mostly use PIC Basic type languages (such as Swordfish) that will land you code that looks something like this (header/setup removed for ease of explanation):

```
While True
    High(LED)
    DelaymS(500)
    Low(LED)
    DelaymS(500)
Wend
```